# Swiper Slider - continue to next slide when video ends

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper Slider on my platform, I know how to set each slide timings differently but when it comes to video slides the matter is a tad more complicated. If the video doesn't load immediately, setting up a fixed slide time to move to the next one is not a guaranteed method to make sure the video has finished playing.

Is there I way a can fire the next slide in swiper slider only when the video in a slide has reached the end?

Thank you for your help,

Alessio

Comment: Looks like "Swiper Slider" is based on client-side/browser web technologies and is highly controllable via these. You'll need to program some Javascript for your desired functionality (unless Swiper's API already provides for a "transition slide on AV end event"). Ayhoo, read https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp and https://framework7.io/docs/swiper.html#swiper-app-methods

Comment: yes, looks like the plugin is super customizable.  Have you tried anything yet?  If so post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I use `data-swiper-autoplay` attribute inn combination with Javascript. I get my video's duration and add it as a value for that attribute in ms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).